# iTunesMobileDevice.dll Could not be found

Tags: ios, visual-c++, itunes, win32-process, mobile-devices

I am writing a windows application that interfaces with an iOS device. I am using mobiledevice.h header to interface with iTunes dll

http://samdmarshall.com/media/MobileDevice.h

I made sure i set the system environment path includes the Apple application support. I made sure in the project properties I added the correct .lib in the linker. I made sure in the compiler property I included all the directories in the Additional library field.

It builds, but during run time I get this error:

Unable to load DLL 'iTunesMobileDevice.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

I tried to copy the dll and place it in the same directory as the project and the debug .exe, but still the same issue when running. I've also ran dependency walker, but the only thing it said it couldnt find is IESHIMS.dll.

I can't think of anything else to try. I'm sorry if this is not detailed. If anyone needs anymore detail please let me know and I will add as much as I can.

UPDATE: SOLVED, just had to include the directory in the system paths if anyone else needs the solution

Comment: can you type the system path you used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had to add the directories to the System path which could be found under

start -> right click computer -> properties -> advanced system settings -> environment variables -> system variables -> Path

In path separate the different directories with a ';'.

Comment: Can you type the system path you used.